# System.IO.FileLoadException: Exception raised in RichEditBox document

Tags: exception, uwp, richeditbox

[image]

Hi, I have a user control that extends RichEditBox, we have a TextChanged Property, we bind a string variable to the Text Property, and the error shown in the image is generated within the TextChanged function, I am not sure why this error is being generated.. Any clue would be helpful.

For further information,  Document.Selection is not null, Document.Selection.Text does show the last string bound to it, TASK_DONE_SYMBOL is not null either.

We have a page with a lot of items, each item has a RichEditBox, and when we update some of the items, sometimes, not always, does this issue come up.

Comment: I created a blank sample that append `Document.Selection.Text` in `TextChanged`, it could works, but the  `TextChanged` will keep trigger, we need set a flag to stop this. Unfortunately, I could not reproduce your issue. Could you share  [mcve] for us?

Comment: Hi, so we were using  x:Bind to bind text with the richeditbox, and we also used x:Phase, when we use both of them together, exceptions are often thrown, however if we remove x:Phase, it works okay, can you have a guess as to why it's working?  Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Nico Zhu - MSFT, we have already been using that!

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-phase-attribute). Use x:Phase with the {x:Bind} markup extension to render ListView and GridView items incrementally and improve the panning experience. You can't use it RichEditBox control

Comment: Actually, two RichEditBox and two images go in the ListViewItem template, so we are using x:Phase to incrementally load the elements for each ListViewItem

Comment: Could share your xaml code ?